# arcpy.SetParameter() - Problem passing escaped string as geoprocessing service output

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I have a geoservice that get some text stored from a table in order to return a json string to a javascript client.

However, the `arcpy.SetParameter()` seems to have problem to returns the escaped new lines character (`\\n`)

```
my_dict = {"key1" : "test is a string with\nsome escaped characters\nsuch newlines"}

my_json = json.dumps(my_dict)
print(my_json)
>>> '{"key1": "test is a string with\\nsome escaped characters\\nsuch newlines"}'

arcpy.SetParameter(0, my_json)
```

in the javascript console the response is the following which is not a valid json:

```
{"key1" : "test is a string with
some escaped characters
such newlines"}
```

Is there a solution? Someone can confirm that the problem is with `arcpy.SetParameter()` function?

Comment: Will the string eventually be used as html?

Comment: there is no html tag in the string, but yes it will inserted in a html page somewhere.

Comment: Have you considered replacing the escaped characters with <br> ? `test is a string with <br>some escaped characters <br> such newlines`

Comment: Kludgy, yes this is the workaround I have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened a discussion on [Esri GeoNet forum](https://geonet.esri.com/message/655390-re-arcpysetparameter-problem-passing-escaped-string-as-geoprocessing-service-output) with this issue.

For what I have found, this is really a problem (read bug) with `arcpy.SetParameter()` which seems to not handle multilines strings.

The workaround would be to replace the `\\n` characters in the string with something else such `<br>` before passing it through the `arcpy.SetParameter()`.

Then, in the javascript application, we have to replace the `<br>` back to `\n` .

In the python code:

```
my_dict = {"key1" : "test is a string with\nsome escaped characters\nsuch newlines"}

my_json = json.dumps(my_dict)
print(my_json)
>>> '{"key1": "test is a string with\\nsome escaped characters\\nsuch newlines"}'

my_json_with_br = my_json.replace("\\n", "<br>")
print(my_json_with_br)
>>>'{"key1": "test is a string with<br>some escaped characters<br>such newlines"}'
arcpy.SetParameter(0, my_json_with_br)
```

In the javascript:

```
var well_formated_string = my_json_with_br["key1"].replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "\n")
console.log(well_formated_string)
>>>"test is a string with
some escaped characters
such newlines"
```